# How do i remove this extended content?

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a web messenger and I wanted to remove the bar where my cursor is:

[image: page]

Home.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.texter')

@section('content')


<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" style="width: 32.5% !important; border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">
                    <div class="user-row">
                        <img src="{{asset('/images/conta.png')}}" alt="" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; cursor: pointer;">

                        <span style="float: right; margin-top: 10px; cursor: pointer;">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
                                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12 7a2 2 0 1 0-.001-4.001A2 2 0 0 0 12 7zm0 2a2 2 0 1 0-.001 3.999A2 2 0 0 0 12 9zm0 6a2 2 0 1 0-.001 3.999A2 2 0 0 0 12 15z">     
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        
                            

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="card-body" id="app">
                    <chat-app :user="{{ auth()->user() }}"></chat-app>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
@endsection
```

If I go to the layouts.texter and remove it's nav bars and it's content my whole page goes blank.

[image: blade that i dupped]
[image: home blade]

I just wanted my home blade to show with no bar on the top, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the navbar? its defined as nav in your texter.blade.php 
does it not work to remove everything from <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md.......">
down to the closing </nav>?
```

Comment: If i remove this whole thing : https://i.imgur.com/wtTlme9.png my whole page goes blank

Comment: It was making my whole page go blank but It's working now, i did `npm run dev`  and  its seems to have worked, thanks anyway